# SQL auto-indentation in VS Code

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I am learning SQL (PostgreSQL). As the code gets longer and more complicated, it gets harder to review in PGadmin visually. Is there any way to auto-indent in VS Code like in SQL Server

I have tried SQL formatter extension from VS Code marketplace. It indents the codes. But in 'C' style. When I have 3 or 4 subqueries, it isn't easy to keep track of the indention

Comment: "*And I can not accept they manually indent real-time codes!!!*" What did developers do before IDEs that handled indentation on the developer's behalf, do you think?

Comment: The only time I use automatic formatting is when I need to take un-formatted SQL statements from a log file (or a badly written question on SO). Formatting your SQL so that it's readable and easy to understand is much better done manually.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to your vscode extension marketplace and search for SQL code formatter. I found one by just searching on google real quick. [SQL Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adpyke.vscode-sql-formatter)

Comment: It does indention in C style. I keep losing track of which FROM is related to which SELECT

Comment: find another one, if that doesn't work for you. Just go to your vscode extension marketplace and search for SQL code formatter.